# projects disappear from VS 2015 solution after reopening

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a weird problem with my C# solution file. I noticed that my .sln file itself was missing. So I created an empty .sln file, added my Existing projects to it, built and it worked fine. When I close and reopen Visual Studio, the .sln file I created is there but projects added to the solution have disappeared. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are having issues with write permissions in your solution. Is the folder your solution is in under any type of source control?

Try creating a new folder at the root of your harddrive. Something like c:\testsolution
Copy your project files there and then try adding you solution file again.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes this folder is under git. Should I be fixing my git settings? If so what should I look for?

Comment: If you're using git I don't think this is your issue. I have know others like TFS to lock files until they see it as being checked out, but git should let you edit and save at your leisure.

If you have the solution project file open elsewhere, such as in a text editor, that may also cause it to not save.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is an issue with not saving the changes to VS solution file.

Before closing Visual Studio, take an extra step to make sure all changes are actually saved  (File-> Save All). Then manually verify that all your projects successfully made it to the solution file by opening the solution file with a text editor. If you don't see your projects listed, try editing the file yourself to verify you have the necessary permissions.